# ScreenUpdating = False fails in Excel 2013 and 2016

Tags: vba, excel

Long-running, high-end Excel-based applications that I developed years ago and that run beautifully in Excel 2007 and 2010 look like Amateur Hour in Excel 2013 and 2016 because `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` no longer works reliably.

The screen unfreezes apparently when VBA code copies a preformatted worksheet from the macro workbook into a new workbook, although other circumstances must trigger it as well.

I’ve seen the threads on this subject that recommend “fiddling with the code” or “calling the code in a subroutine”.  Unfortunately, I have to maintain hundreds of Excel applications each with thousands of lines of code and hundreds of users who are about to migrate to Office 2016, so rewriting is not an option.  How can I recover Excel’s former elegance?

Comment: FWIW, I found that `DoEvents` can lead to unexpected events being processed, which can lead to re-enabling ScreenUpdating.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look into that.  I've always put a DoEvents in every loop, so changing programs won't be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a technique that helps reduce flickering and preserves the StatusBar message.

```
Application.Cursor = xlWait
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
. . .
Set wkbNewBook = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
. . .
ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
wkbNewBook.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Cursor = xlDefault
```

Comment: Have you noticed if this method also improves the macro speed like when `.ScreenUpdating = false` works correctly?

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to improve the speed more than just specifying .ScreenUpdating = false.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ideas:

- Check if your code calls for code in a different procedure, maybe the Application.ScreenUpdating is turned on outside of the procedure.
- Try this at the beginning of your procedure:

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Then, at the end of the code set it to:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: this doesn't work in all cases. For example, I am leaving workbooks open while I create new workbooks and indirect in all the date. Leaving calculations to manual won't help speed up the process as I will need to run calculate every time I open a new workbook.

Answer (score 1):

We have been dealing with this problem now for a long time as my tools do show live animated charts which all of the sudden were completely static - we would have died for having at  least a flickering animation.

Initially we tried to force the animation with a forced screenupdate but that did not work. Just by pure coincidence (copy pasted too many times) we stumbled into a solution which is equally unbelievable as it does seem to work. After each `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` we have added x3 times DoEvents. On some systems x2 times DoEvents works but x3 times does seem to be more reliable on the various office releases out there. Voila our animation came back :-)

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

DoEvents

DoEvents

DoEvents
```

We have not used it for the `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` statement but it might do some magic there.

Answer (score 0):

After looking through many forums, I believe the flicker problem is related to SDI vs MDI.
Someone suggested setting the application to not visible.

```
Application.Visible=False
enter code here
Application.Visible=True
```

This solved my flicker problem, but I didn't like how the excel application disappeared completely then suddenly reappeared for the user.

I was able to solve the issue to my liking by using a workaround this 'which window is on top' problem.

By leaving the main window alone, and forcing other workbooks to become not visible, letting the code run, then bringing them back to visible, it stopped flickering.

```
Application.Workbooks("yourworkbooktohide").Windows(1).Visible = False
```

Just remember to bring it back with =true.

Again, my script worked just fine in Excel 2010, but after "upgrading" to 2013, this flicker issue started.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, King123.  I have been experimenting with this technique, and although it doesn’t stop the flickering completely, it improves the result in an important way:  It restores visibility to the StatusBar message, which I update every few seconds to show the application’s progress.  Making the new output workbook invisible will crash the program during some operations, but making the macro workbook invisible after adding the new output workbook seems to suppress all but one flicker, and it preserves the StatusBar display.

Answer (score 0):

For me, only "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" did not completely cure the flickering.
Calculation caused also the flickering.
Adding "Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual" solved the flickering issue.
So, the code should be like:

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

... important code here....

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and, believe it or not, it was solved by unplugging and reconnecting the cable of my second monitor. This cable is using a HDMI to VGA converter.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).